# Generating date in Oracle using prepared statements

Tags: java, oracle, date, prepared-statement

I have an interesting problem here.  I'm trying to generate an XML date using the Oracle `to_char` command.  When I do this using PL/SQL everything works fine:

```
18:05:54 SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss".000Z"') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DDT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-04-10T23:09:50.000Z
```

However, when I put that date format into a Java program and use a prepared statement it throws a very strange and meaningless error of "Missing IN OUT parameter at index:: 6" which is strange because there are only 5 parameters.  I know it is the date format because if I alter the format the command works fine.

Here is my date format string and the one that works:

```
private static final String XML_DATE = ", 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MM:SS\"Z\")";  <-- BROKEN

private static final String XML_DATE = ", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS')";  <-- Working
```

You may notice that I needed to escape the quotation marks to keep them in the string.

A little additional information.  This string is inserted in-line from the main prepared statement.  That's why it looks a little funny.  So each line of my SQL statement looks like this:

```
    "   NVL(to_char(flt.my_date_dtm" + XML_DATE + ",'') my_date_dtm, " +
```

The actual error tossed is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 6
```

Again, which is strange because there are 5 parameters.  Anybody have any ideas as to why it's doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing single-quote in the 'broken' one:

```
private static final String XML_DATE = ", 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MM:SS\"Z\")";
                                                                         ^
```

You've also changed `MI` to `MM` in both the broken and working one versions. So it should be:

```
private static final String XML_DATE = ", 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS\"Z\"')";
```

Not sure if you've intentionally left out the `.000` part.

I think that's throwing the parsing off and it's making a colon later in the constructed string be interpreted as a bind variable. As you aren't getting a missing-quote error you're presumably using this format twice in the final string (or an even number of times, anyway) so overall you do end up with valid strings. Kind of - long and meaningless, but with balanced quotes at least...

When I see an error like that and can't immediately spot the problem, I usually write the final string out to console and try to run that through SQL*Plus, which tends to make the problem rather more obvious.

Comment: OMG!  Thank you!  You don't know how many people I've had look at this stupid statement and could not find that.  Always helpful to have another pair of eyes!

Comment: "and it's making a colon later in the constructed string be interpreted as a bind variable"...

Ok, this solved my issue.  I took the ' characters out of my prepared statement and my bind variables magically started working properly.  Amazing!